# When is $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$ for positive definite $A$ and positive semidefinite $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, determinant, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix and $B$ be a positive semi-definite matrix. Under what conditions does $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$ hold?

We all know that for any two positive semi-definite matrices $A$ and $B$, $\det(A+B) \geq \det(A)+\det(B)$ and strict inequality holds when $A$ and $B$ are both positive definite matrices having order $\geq 2$. My question is that under what conditions on $A$ (positive definite) and $B$ (positive semi-definite) the reverse also holds true, that is, the equality holds? Please help.

Best regards,

Prasenjit Ghosh.

Comment: Sorry, what are these abbreviations? I guess, '*p.d.*' stands for '*positive definite*', but '*n.n.d.*'?

Comment: I am extremely sorry for not using the complete terminology. Yes,by "p.d." I meant positive definite and by "n.n.d." I meant non-negative definite (positive semi-definite).

Comment: The 0 matrix and identity works. Maybe a few more

Answer (score 7):

When $A\succ0$ and $B\succeq0$, $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$ if and only if $B=0$ or $n=1$. Hints:

1. $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$ is equivalent to $\det(I+A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})=1+\det(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})$.
2. So you are essentially asking when does $\det(I+X)=1+\det(X)$ hold for a positive semidefinite $X$. WLOG you may assume that $X$ is diagonal.

Comment: I thought at first you were wrong about what comes after #2, but I was mistaken about that. ☺ +1.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Uhh, sorry for the confusion. There is actually no need to reduce $X$ to a diagonal matrix, as we may think directly in terms of eigenvalues, but I am too used to transform everything to a simpler form first, despite doing so may be redundant.

Comment: I know, I do suffer the simplification bug myself. I think my students are mystified sometimes when I rephrase a question just so I don't have to deal with a random constant through a lengthy calculation, but I keep doing it anyway.